# How to map an intermediate table in Hibernate

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I wish to map an intermediate table that looks like this:

[image]

This is how my user class looks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User

@Id
@Column(name = "user_id")
private int id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name="FAVORITES",
joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_user_id", 
                          referencedColumnName = "user_id"), 
inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "fk_content_id", 
                          referencedColumnName = "content_id"))
private Set<Content> favorites;
```

And this is how my content class looks:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "content")
public class Content

@Id
@Column(name="content_id")
private int id;
```

The objects persist correctly, but not in the favorites table, instead only the ids 0 are saved.

Where i create the objects:

```
public void registerUser(User tempUser) {
    Session session = this.SessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    Content con = new Content();
    Set<Content> favs = new HashSet<Content>();
    favs.add(con);
    tempUser.setFavorites(favs);
    session.save(tempUser);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
}
```

And a log:

```
Hibernate: select content_.content_id from contents content_ where content_.content_id=?
Hibernate: insert into users (user_id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into contents (content_id) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into FAVORITES (fk_user_id, fk_content_id) values (?, ?)
```

Image of what is persisted in the DB:

[image]

Comment: but you dont post the code where the objects are created, and then persisted, and indeed what the JPA provider does (by looking in its log).

Comment: Edited to add more info.

Comment: Maybe it's because you are not adding any content to con  variable?

Comment: Also you are referring sometimes as table content, and others (log file) to contents

Comment: The code shown never sets the ID values, so they would be 0 in the database, matching the FK values you are showing in the favorites table

Comment: Isn't JPA suppose to do that on it's own once the objects are persisted?

Comment: This is NOT the JPA API. It is the Hibernate API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, the problem being Hibernate wouldn't give the intermediate table the id of the 2 other since the ids weren't generated before the objects were persisted.
I had to give up on the autogenerated ids and give ids that i had access to before persisting the objects.
This solved the problem.

Comment: can you please explain with code how did you do that? I am a beginner and I do not understand.